# Image Slider using UIScrollView and Auto Layout

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, ios-autolayout, uipagecontrol

I am trying to implement a image slider using scrollView and pageControl, with the images being appended to the scrollView programmatically using the .addSubView method. The code is as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderPageControl: UIPageControl!
var images: [String] = ["0", "1", "2"]

func updateSlider() {
        sliderPageControl.numberOfPages = images.count

        for index in 0..<images.count {
            frame.origin.x = sliderScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            print(sliderScrollView.frame.size.width)
            frame.size = sliderScrollView.frame.size

            let image = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            image.image = UIImage(named: cafeObject.images[index])
            sliderScrollView.addSubview(image)
        }
        sliderScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: sliderScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(cafeObject.images.count), height: sliderScrollView.frame.size.height)
        sliderScrollView.delegate = self
        sliderPageControl.currentPage = 0
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width

    switch scrollView {
    case sliderScrollView:
        sliderPageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

As I designed the storyboard on iPhone 8 layout, the above code works nicely for iPhone 8. However, once I run the code in iPhone 8 Plus, the photo does not adapt the new size of the scrollView. I have added constraints to the scrollView such that the top, leading, trailing and bottom are equal to the super view's top, leading, trailing and bottom. When debugging, I realized that the UIImageView's frame is still using the old width as on iPhone 8.

Any workaround for this either programatically or using interface builder? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to get this fixed by placing the updateSlider() function under `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead!